# How to update marker positions with data from Firebase Google Maps API Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, marker

I'm creating an app that makes a real time tracking of users using Firebase Database. Every user is displayed in the map using markers.

When there is a new location update, the marker has to be updated. The problem is that with Firebase method onDataChange() or similars every time a new location update is retrieved, I can't access to the old marker to remove it and create a new one or just update the old marker, because the marker doesn't exist.

I tried it saving markers in SharedPreferences using Gson, but when I pass the marker to json, the app crashes.

Does anyone know how can I update the markers?

This is written inside the onDataChange():

```
           for (User user: usersList) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                /*
                String previousJson = preferences.getString(user.getId()+"-marker", "");
                Marker previousMarker = gson.fromJson(previousJson, Marker.class);
                if (previousMarker!=null) markerAnterior.remove();
                */

                final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(user.getLastLocation().getLatitude(), user.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latlng)
                        .title(user.getId());

                Marker marker= mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

             //   String newJson = gson.toJson(marker); //CRASH
            //    editor.putString(user.getId()+"-marker", newJson);
            //    editor.commit();

            }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a HashMap instance variable that will map user IDs to Markers:

```
private Map<String, Marker> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, populate new Markers in the HashMap so you can retrieve them later.

If the Marker already exists, just update the location:

```
for (User user : usersList) {

    final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(user.getLastLocation().getLatitude(), user.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

    Marker previousMarker = mMarkerMap.get(user.getId());
    if (previousMarker != null) {
        //previous marker exists, update position:
        previousMarker.setPosition(latlng);
    } else {
        //No previous marker, create a new one:
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng)
                .title(user.getId());

        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //put this new marker in the HashMap:
        mMarkerMap.put(user.getId(), marker);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the HashMap out of the onDataChange() of Firebase and it seems that it worked!! But why? Firebase calls are asynchronous so every new location the mMarkerMap it is supposed to by null, am I wrong?

Comment: @smartgg Yes,  `mMarkerMap` needs to be a class-level instance variable, defined outside of any method.  Can you clarify more about why you don't understand why it works?  The Firebase calls just get you the current snapshot of data.  You have to keep track of existing Markers locally in the app, and that is what the HashMap does.

Comment: Thank you. I told u that because when I try to return some data from Firebase, if for example i declare an ArrayList outside of onDataChange and I add some values on it inside onDataChange, the ArrayList don't have any values saved when I call it outside of onDataChange.

Comment: @smartgg If you declare the ArrayList as a class-level instance variable, it should contain all of the data added to it, as long as the app isn't quit and re-launched.

Comment: @DanielNugent can you please take a look at my problem .[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731956/map-markers-disappearing-when-activity-gets-refreshed). Thank you