# Google Maps Displays two Markers when Marker Moved

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Google Maps Android SDK to populate the map with markers whose locations are stored in a Firebase database common to all users of my application. Data for each marker is stored in a unique Firebase record and each record contains the Latitude & Longitude of the marker along with a boolean value indicating if the location has been verified.
Markers are initially added to the Map via the childAdded listener. The App then "Listens" to the Firebase database for the following events:

- A new marker is added
- An existing marker is changed(moved to a new location and/or "verified")
- An existing marker is deleted

I have implemented a hash map as shown in [How to update marker positions with data from Firebase Google Maps API Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681030/how-to-update-marker-positions-with-data-from-firebase-google-maps-api-android).

When a marker is added, entries are added to a hash map where the Firebase pushID (key) is used as the index to the marker object in the hash map (see code below).

```
    private Map<String, Marker> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<> ();
```

```
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();
        DatabaseReference markerRef = dbRef.child ( "markers" );
        //load all markers when app starts
        //child added returns all markers, then listens for new additions
        //Log.i(TAG, "Database Reference: " + dbRef);
        //List<SymbolOptions> options = new ArrayList<> ();
        markerRef.addChildEventListener ( new ChildEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                try {
                    markerKey = dataSnapshot.getKey ();
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Adding Markers: " );
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Marker Key: " + markerKey );
                    double x = (Double) dataSnapshot.child ( "x" ).getValue ();
                    double y = (Double) dataSnapshot.child ( "y" ).getValue ();
                    boolean v = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child ( "v" ).getValue ();
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Marker Data - x: " + x + " y: " + y + " v: " + v );
                    if (v == true) {
                        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .position ( new LatLng ( y, x ) )
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.verified ) ) );
                        marker.setTag(markerKey);
                        mMarkerMap.put (markerKey, marker);
                    } else {
                        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .position ( new LatLng ( y, x ) )
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.unverified ) ) );
                        marker.setTag(markerKey);
                        mMarkerMap.put (markerKey, marker);
                    }
                } catch (Error error) {
                    noFirebaseAccessAlert ();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                try {
                    markerKey = dataSnapshot.getKey ();
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Changing Marker: " );
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Marker Key: " + markerKey );
                    double x = (Double) dataSnapshot.child ( "x" ).getValue ();
                    double y = (Double) dataSnapshot.child ( "y" ).getValue ();
                    boolean v = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child ( "v" ).getValue ();
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Marker Data - x: " + x + " y: " + y + " v: " + v );
                    Marker changedMarker = mMarkerMap.get(markerKey);
                    if (v == true) {
                        changedMarker.setPosition (new LatLng(y,x));
                        changedMarker.setIcon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.verified ) );
                    } else {
                        changedMarker.setPosition (new LatLng(y,x));
                        changedMarker.setIcon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.unverified ) );
                    }
                } catch (Error error) {
                    noFirebaseAccessAlert ();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    markerKey = dataSnapshot.getKey ();
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Deleting Marker: " );
                    Log.i ( TAG, "Marker Key: " + markerKey );
                    Marker deletedMarker = mMarkerMap.get (markerKey);
                    deletedMarker.remove ();
                    mMarkerMap.remove(markerKey);
                } catch (Error error) {
                    noFirebaseAccessAlert ();
                }
            }
```

The problem is that when the data is changed in Firebase and the "childChanged" listener is called, a new icon is placed on the map at the updated location, but the original icon remains.
No new entry is made to the hash table.

If I tap on either icon, the "onClickMarker" function receives the same marker identifier.
I could simply delete the existing marker and add a new one, but would rather move the existing marker if possible.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Found the problem.  Not a google map problem.  Another routine was calling the code above twice, thus adding two markers on top of each other.  when I moved one, the other remained.  Above code works fine.

Comment: Updated are code to add "tag" so that "onClickMarker" can identify correct marker that is tapped.

Comment: above code has been tested and works properly.

Answer (score 2):

In Your code Issue is here

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .position ( new LatLng ( y, x ) )
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.verified ) ) );
```

You create every time new Marker object, No need to create every time new Marker object,you have to just set your marker position after create object once.like below code..

```
Marker marker;

            if (mMap != null) {
                if (marker == null) {
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(mLatlng)
                            .title(mCity);
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                } else {
                    marker.setPosition(mLatlng);
                }
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatlng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatlng, 15f));
            }
```

Comment: Thanks - if you are referring to the adding of markers in the "childAdded" listener, it is adding all existing markers in Firebase to the map when the listener is initially invoked and then listens for any additions that are made to the database.  The "childChanged" listener then modifies an existing marker if it detects a change in the Firebase data for that specific marker fetching the marker object using the hash map.  The "childRemoved" listener removes a specific marker from both the map and the hash map if it detects a marker has been removed.  Agree??